# Synchronizing the Progress Bar with the Timer

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar

I want to update my ProgressBar simultaneously with the audio file on clicking the Button. I had also used the timer which runs according to the length of the audio file which is in seconds.

I have configured the Timer and it is nicely increasing according to the length of the audio file but my ProgressBar is not working. It gives me NumberFormatException.

My Code:
     class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
          {
            private int mycount;

```
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
        {
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {
          //timeDisplay.setText("done!");
        }
        public void onTick(long millsIncreasing) 
        {

        mycount++;
        mystring = formatTime(mycount*1000);
        myText.setText(mystring); 
        pBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(mystring));  (*****)
        pBar.setProgress(1000 * pBar.getProgress());
        /*String myString1 = mystring.substring(0, mystring.lastIndexOf(":")).trim();
        String myString2 = mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf(":")+1, mystring.length()).trim();*/
```

I am getting the Exception on the line where I have shown the Stars in the BRACKET.
Can anybody please help me,
Thanks
david

Comment: can you please post the code for the `formatTime` function? does it return a formated Integer?

Comment: Can you debug it and/or log what mystring is when you get the exception?

Comment: Why are you converting your numeric "mycount" to a time string and then trying to convert it back to an integer?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, Here is my FormatTime Function's code:

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, 
public String formatTime(long millis)
   {
     String output = "00:00";
     long seconds = millis / 1000;
     long minutes = seconds / 60;
    
     
     seconds = seconds % 60;
     minutes = minutes % 60;
    

     String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
     String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
    

     if (seconds < 10)
       secondsD = "0" + seconds;
     if (minutes < 10)
       minutesD = "0" + minutes;
    
     output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
     return output;
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function is returning a String "12:34" (with the : in middle) that is not a number format that Integer.parse can parse.

You should keep a variable which will hold the value of the file time length (in seconds)

```
int fileLength
```

then in your function:

```
public void onTick(long millsIncreasing) 
{
    int progress = (int)Math.round(millsIncreasing / fileLength) * 100;
    Bar.setProgress(progress);
```

this is assuming that the `millsIncreasing` parameter is the ms. processed so far.